# How can I check for available disk space?

Tags: c#, asp.net, diskspace

I need a way to check available disk space on a **remote** Windows server before copying files to that server.  Using this method I can check to see if the primary server is full and if it is, then I'll copy the files to a secondary server.

How can I check for available disk space using C#/ASP.net 2.0?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715/best-way-to-query-disk-space-on-remote-server

Answer (score 31):

You can check it by doing the following:

Add the `System.Management.dll` as a reference to your project.

Use the following code to get the diskspace:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public string GetFreeSpace();
{ 
   ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
   disk.Get();
   string freespace = disk["FreeSpace"];
   return freespace;
}
```

There are a myriad of ways to do it, I'd check the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace for more ways.

Here's one such way from that page:

```
public void GetDiskspace()
    {
      ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
      ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2", 
      options);
      scope.Connect();
      ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
      SelectQuery query1 = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");

      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
      ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query1);
      ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = searcher1.Get();

      foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
      {
          // Display the remote computer information

          Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}", m["csname"]);
          Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}", m["WindowsDirectory"]);
          Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}", m["Caption"]);
          Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);
          Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}", m["Manufacturer"]);
          Console.WriteLine();
      }

      foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection1)
      {
          // Display Logical Disks information

         Console.WriteLine("              Disk Name : {0}", mo["Name"]);
         Console.WriteLine("              Disk Size : {0}", mo["Size"]);
         Console.WriteLine("              FreeSpace : {0}", mo["FreeSpace"]);
         Console.WriteLine("          Disk DeviceID : {0}", mo["DeviceID"]);
         Console.WriteLine("        Disk VolumeName : {0}", mo["VolumeName"]);
         Console.WriteLine("        Disk SystemName : {0}", mo["SystemName"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Disk VolumeSerialNumber : {0}", mo["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
      string line;
      line = Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Comment: This works for the machine that is executing the code, but what about for a remote server?

Comment: The link I sent you to can tell you how; I've not done it; but I can post the code you'd use to query the server.

Comment: Ah okay, I missed the ManagementScope, this should work for me then.  I'll give it a try

Answer (score 18):

by using this code

```
 static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(@"C:");
            long FreeSpace = driveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace;
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException errorMesage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMesage);
        }

    }
```

IF you are getting the error '**The device is not ready**' .i.e your device is not ready .
If you are trying this code for a CD drive without CD you will get the same error : )

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be an option from the System.IO:

```
DriveInfo c = new DriveInfo("C");
long cAvailableSpace = c.AvailableFreeSpace;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the DriveInfo class

```
DriveInfo[] oDrvs = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (var Drv in oDrvs) {
        if (Drv.IsReady) {
            Console.WriteLine(Drv.Name + " " + Drv.AvailableFreeSpace.ToString);
        }
}
```

Comment: This works for the machine that is executing the code, but what about for a remote server?

Comment: You could map a network drive, but it may be a little complicated to do programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI, see this related question:

[Best way to query disk space on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715/best-way-to-query-disk-space-on-remote-server)