# See the AvailableFreeSpace of drives via IP-Address

Tags: c#, driveinfo

I know that, AvailableFreeSpace is possible to use for local drives such as "C:/", "D:/" etc.
It also works on network drives.

But now my question is:

Is it possible to view the AvailableFreeSpace of a "Folder" on another IP?
I connect to the local drives with this code:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo _DriveInfo = new DriveInfo(SaveLocation);
```

When "SaveLocation" is a local drive like "C:\Temp\Folder", than it works fine.

But when there is an IP inside "SaveLocation" it doesn't work. SaveLocation looks like this in that case: "192.168.200.10\c\Data"

This doesn't work and that is the reason for my question. The Exceptionmessage is: {"Object must be a root directory (\"C:\\") or a drive letter (\"C\")."}

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What if you add shared location as a mapped drive and check its free space?

Comment: @dotctor mapped drives works, but I only get the string (I don't have influence about it). The string is an IP most of the time and I can't add each IP I get as mapped drive. The programitically mapping is to long because I have to create it each time I get the string and dissolve it after the save is finished. ( I have to that because there is a possibility that i can get a lot of different IP's)

Comment: WMI is a little trickier but I think you can ask for the available space using it. Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412395/how-can-i-check-for-available-disk-space. It's using localhost but you could extract the IP. The only thing I know cannot be done is to convert a UNC to the actual local path in the remote machine, unless you have administrator rights, so if remote machines have more than one drive it might not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in [Get available disk free space for a given path on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465187/get-available-disk-free-space-for-a-given-path-on-windows) :

Use the winapi function `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` to determine free space on a UNC (network) path. For example, create a new VS Project called FreeSpace and paste this as Program.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace FreeSpace
    {
        class Program
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
                                        out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
                                        out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
                                        out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ulong FreeBytesAvailable;
                ulong TotalNumberOfBytes;
                ulong TotalNumberOfFreeBytes;

                bool success = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(@"\\NETSHARE\folder",
                                              out FreeBytesAvailable,
                                              out TotalNumberOfBytes,
                                              out TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
                if (!success)
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

                Console.WriteLine("Free Bytes Available:      {0,15:D}", FreeBytesAvailable);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Number Of Bytes:     {0,15:D}", TotalNumberOfBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Number Of FreeBytes: {0,15:D}", TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is the exact same code as in the Question linked above, just factored into a class plus the correct `using` directives to compile without error. All credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire

WMI doesn't seem to handle free space on network shares.
But for local disks, Windows Management Interface is the way to go:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This works for Mapped Drives but not for an IP-adress without the mapping. So sadly this does not work in my case

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for you. Alternatively, you could also use the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx winapi function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465187/get-available-disk-free-space-for-a-given-path-on-windows

Comment: The [DLLImport] variant worked! Thanks! Can you formulate an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Just edited my answer with a link to the existing question. I'm not sure, isn't this a duplicate to the linked question? If so, should we flag it?

Comment: Not necessarily. He wants a folder or a mapped drive. I want to connect to a folder via IP-Address and not mapped or local drives. I change my question, so it could be clear